# How does MergeContent works in Apache NiFi?

Tags: json, merge, apache-nifi

I've been trying to merge the content in my workFlow based on filename, from three different XMLs, converting it in JSON, splitting it and, then, merging it in one WorkFlow. I'm trying to have a single JSON for each day, but if I put only one MergeContent, it doesn't work properly. If I put two, it works.

This is my processors

[image]

procesado_xml:

[image]

split_and_merge:

[image]

Properties of MergeContent:

[image]

And demarcator = ","+shift intro

***My question is:***

Why sometimes it works merging workFlows in two different workflows and sometimes it works merging all workFlows in only one?

folder format: "test"+yyyyMMddhhmm

file format: date-of-origin+"_prueba"+ss.SSSSSS.json

Finally desired 28's file has 13 107 rows, 6,4 Mb
When it generates two different WorkFlows, first of it has 8 107 rows and the second one has 4 999 (one row is missing?)

If I put only one MergeContent:
[image]

If I put two MergeContent like in the previous processor's image, it works like the previous one. Sometimes it works properly, sometimes not

How can I ensure that NiFi merge it in only one workFlow?

Comment: to be sure you put all flow files in one use Defragment Merge Strategy

Comment: If I use Defragment Merge Strategy, I need to set up the labels fragment.identifier, fragment.count, fragment.index.... I'm not sure how many rows I'll receive from splitJson. How can I build this attributes?

Comment: SplitJson already produces those attributes. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html

Comment: It gives me an Idea. I see problems if I will try to merge several files (at the beginning, previous to splitJson, it has 3 files), I'll be able to merge rows of each file, but not these files between them. If I would like to do that, probably I need to merge it after that with a Bin-Packing strategy, is that right?

I will have problems if I try to merge it at once because fragment.index and fragment.count will give me problems, the number of rows always be more than fragment.count if I try to merge 2 or more files...